# Sci-fi film about hacking, villain is a computer-generated picture, boy destroys him by adding “small figures with a baseball bat” over him

Tags: story-identification, movie

Old sci-fi movie. Similar age (and effects) to *Lawnmover Man* or *WarGames*, probably from 80s or 90s.

In his home, the boy interacts with some computer figure (talking face on screen), that was initially good, but then somehow needs to be stopped to stop some problems.

Boy finally destroys it using some “stick-figures with a baseball bat” over the screen, beating the face - probably caused deleting of it, or something.

Comment: This sounds like Hackers(1995). But romance come very late and I dont remember any motor destroy computer scene.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I believe my "heroes" were a bit younger. And there were lot less action in the movie.

Comment: Masterminds (1997)?

 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJ7sjitftNg

 Antitrust (2001) ?  Avalon (2001)?The Thirteenth Floor (1999)? So many to choose from

Comment: jo1storm: I've checked them all - unfortunately, none of those are the one I am searching for. My movie was a bit older - definitely before 2000. And definitely less shooting scenes. If there is any other on your mind, please tell :-)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloak_%26_Dagger_(1984_film) maybe this one? There's a kid in there.  Or this one? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_Man_(1971_film)

1984 Electric Dreams.  Or 


1984 — Hide and Seek  . So many hacker movies... If one of them is correct, I'll make it into a proper answer.

Comment: We are getting closer. The areas, scripts and effects are definitely similar to what I remember. Yet, no match. But definitely worth seeing as well.
Any other suggestions, please?

Comment: @jo1storm Certainly not Avalon. That movie is solid gold btw.

Comment: Ghost in the Machine?  I'm more trying to recall 80s/90s movies with computer faces.  Ghost in the Machine fits the bill and there is a kid in it who is "computer savy".  Virtuosity also has a computer generated face type thing going on, can't completely remember if a kid kills the bad guy in that.  You already mentioned Lawnmower Man.

Comment: Again, thanks for all comments and suggestions. We are still close and I enjoyed every single one of them. Now I started to believe that it might not be movie, but one episode of some movie series. But which one?

Comment: Sure this was a movie?  I think I saw it back then as well, but as an episode of a TV show.  I checked the episode guide for Amazing Stories, but it wasn't any of them.

Comment: Yes, probably was an episode from a TV show.